# How to realise and interprete the interaction term in Cox regression model like this?

Tags: cox-regression

There are two covariates: smoking history(yes or no) and gender(male or female), and the outcome is OA. The author of a paper constructed a Cox regression model with an outcome including this: smoking percentage with sex as a subgroup, and receive hazard ratio of each subgroup.

[Click to show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYXEj.png)

[Original article here.](https://hub.hku.hk/handle/10722/293757#:%7E:text=All%20indices%20of%20HbA1c%20variability%20were%20significant%20independent,across%20groups%20of%20different%20intensity%20of%20glycemic%20control.).

Can the HR be interpreted like this: in males, the HR of having OA in smokers vs. non-smokers is 1.29?

Besides, how can I get the interaction variable of smoking history and gender like that?

Many thanks!

Comment: Interesting question, but off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.